# Converting M4A file to MP3 - Selected files could not be found

Tags: itunes, file-conversion, mp3, ios

**iTunes IOS 12.9 on PC**

I want to convert M4A files (in this case, audiobooks) to MP3. This is what happened.

1. Changed the iTunes import settings to MP3.
2. Selected the book.
3. Selected File > Create MP3 version.

But iTunes displayed None of the selected files could be converted because they could not be found.

I did a general web search and found and tried two purported solutions:
 - Exit and reopen iTunes (did not work)
 - Use Ctrl-A to select all of the tracks (did not work)

In the next post, I explain what did work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To successfully convert from M4A to MP3 on a PC, this is what worked for me.

1. Open iTunes.
2. Change import settings to MP3.
3. Select the file and expand it to see all tracks.
4. Type Ctrl-A to select all tracks. Notice the heart symbol at the left of each track. One or more of the symbols might be "filled in" while others are just an outline of a heart.
5. While holding Ctrl-A, choose each track by toggling to get a "filled in" heart.
6. When all tracks are selected, then go to File > Convert > Create MP3.

The Mp3 files were stored in Users > [username] > Music > iTunes > iTunes Media > Music > [composer/authorname] folder.

Comment: The filled-in heart is the same as "loved this track."

Answer (score 4):

Another solution:

1. Select **View | As Songs** to display the library as a list of tracks (i.e. not organised by album). This is the key part.
2. Then hold the **Control** key and select the songs to be converted by clicking each one.
3. Lastly, select **File | Convert | Create MP3 Version**.

Before doing the above, make sure that the sound encoder is set to **MP3** under **Edit | Preferences | Import Preferences | Import Using ...**

Comment: "1." is the key.